# Problems accessing a PDF file that is in the internal NETWORK in my android application

Tags: android

can someone help me ?

I have an android application that locates the file on the network and gets its URL.

This URL is passed as a parameter when calling the Adobe Reader, but it does not open the document.

The URL format is returning "http://192.168.1.1..........ex.pdf"

This is a code:

The variable DOC is a URL.

```
                    try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(doc), "application/pdf");


                                startActivity(intent);


                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {
                                activityNotFoundException.printStackTrace();


                                throw activityNotFoundException;
                    } catch (Exception otherException) {
                                otherException.printStackTrace();


                                throw otherException;
                    }
                }


                                    if(selectedDocumentURL.contains(".pdf"))
                                    {
                                              try {
                                                        loadDocInReader(selectedDocumentURL);
                                              } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                              }
                                    }else
                                    {
                                    Intent showPic = IntentFactory.createShowPicture(
                                                        WorkOrderDocumentsTable.this, selectedDocumentURL);
                                    startActivity(showPic);
                                    }

                          } else {
                                    showDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.Atte ntion),
                                                        ((Exception) msg.obj).getMessage());
                          }
                          progress.dismiss();
                };
      };
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is you phone connected to the internal network (i.e. via wifi) or is it going through your 3g/4g connection?

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Delete `intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");`.

Step #2: Make sure that the Web server is returning the proper MIME type for your request, as that may trump the MIME type you put in your `Intent`.

Step #3: Make sure that the device can reach this server in general (e.g., via the browser app).

Comment: I realized something. For a syntax error, was getting the file name, not the directory where it was. Now I'm going through the proper address directory, the system does not call AdobeReader, when running loadDocInReader (selectedDocumentURL), he falls into the exception. About your walkthrough, everything already checked too.